# NextJS rewrite automatically converting '//' to '/' in url

Tags: next.js

I have the following entry in my next.config.js file, which points a local path to an external api path.

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api_dev/:path*',
        destination: 'http:/some_api_path:9080/v1/:path*',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

when I pass the url `'/api_dev/param1/test/param2//param3/test'` in my app, nextjs appears to convert the url to `'/api_dev/param1/test/param2/param3/test'`. How do I prevent this from happening? i.e., I want to keep the double forward slash in the url. Is there a way to do this?